# En la versión móvil de la web indica "undefined caracteres restantes"

Tags: bug, interfaz-de-usuario, web-móvil

Al seleccionar la opción de poner un comentario en la versión móvil de la web, si uno no pone nada (yo lo vi al escribir y borrar todo), el conteo da:

> **undefined** caracteres restantes.

Aquí se puede ver:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto deberia ir en meta.. y espera sentado a que toquen algo de la aplicacion movil :(

Comment: Me hicieron una encuesta esta semana, un CM de SO. Vamos a tenerles fe

Comment: @gbianchi por lo que veo, es en la versión para móvil de la web, no en la aplicación.

Comment: @fedorqui tienes toda la razón

Comment: La mayor parte del tiempo uso la versión móvil del sitio web y apenas gracias a tu pregunta noto dicho detalle, gracias por compartirlo

Comment: Reportado en Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334859/209901

Comment: También hay un bug en el *paginate*, pero al preguntar dónde se reporta, la respuesta fue: *ni te molestes, ya que no les interesa repararlo*. Ojalá eso cambiara.